# What is the music being played when Tatara learns to dance from Kiyoharu?

Tags: music, welcome-to-the-ballroom

In episode 2 of *Ballroom e Youkoso*, when Tatara learns to dance from Kiyoharu, what song is playing? I'm referring to the backward-Jazz-piano music [that starts at 1:17 in this YouTube clip](https://youtu.be/wPDPuESUW8I?t=1m17s).

The only songs I can find from this anime are things like OST/OP/ED, not those transitioning instrumentals used whenever someone dances.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to your question but you can't find it because Yuuki Ayashi, the composer of the background music, hasn't released an OST yet.

I was searching for background music too... ^^ Not that particular one, but several pieces of music in the score of this anime.

Guess we have to wait a little more before finding it.

Comment: (OP) ah, so it's an original. Not something that already existed before this anime.